# AWS RDS Network & Security panel not visible

Tags: amazon-rds

I'm new to AWS and I'm having trouble connecting to an Aurora (Postgres compatible) database that I've created.

I can connect to it via the AWS CLI using the following command:

`aws rds-data execute-statement --resource-arn "<my rds cluster ARN>" --database "<My database>" --secret-arn "<My secret in the secret manager>" --sql "select count(*) from information_schema.tables" --profile <my profile>`

and this returns a result of 175 which is correct (the same result I get if I run this in the `query editor` tool in the AWS console.

I then put together a little C# console app and referenced the `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` nuget package as suggested in the AWS docs. When I run it on my PC I get a connection timeout exception.

```
var connectionString = "Server=<My db cluster>; Database=<database name>; User ID=<my user id>; Password=<my password>; Port=5432";

using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
          var sql = "select count(*) from information_schema.tables";
          return connection.ExecuteScalar(sql).ToString();
     }
```

When trying to troubleshoot the problem lots of AWS docs & videos suggest setting the `Public accessibility` property to true by selecting the Db in the RDS console, choosing modify and setting the `Public accessibility` property.

[image]

The only problem is, when I choose to modify the DB, that panel is not visible. The AWS docs & videos do go on to talk about changing inbound rules and whatnot in VPC and subnets but not before they've changed the `Public accessibility` property.

Can anyone advise please?

Comment: I now realize why I can't see the Network & Security panel and therefore can't change the "Public accessibility" option. It's because when I created the DB in question I selected "Serverless" instead of "Provisioned" for the capacity type. Serverless Aurora DB's have all sorts of different characteristics: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps a future reader and as I stated in my comment. The DB in question was created with a capacity type of "Serverless" instead of "Provisioned". Serverless Aurora DB's have all sorts of different characteristics: docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/… One of the characteristics is that they can't be set to publicly accessible.